# Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function in a custom React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a custom hook, but I keep getting the error for the `getToken()` function:

> Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

How do I get around this issue?

```js
export const useExistingToken = async () => {
    const [existingToken, setExistingToken] = useState('')
    const [tokenLocallyExists, tokenLocalCheck] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!tokenLocallyExists) {
            const token = await getToken() // issue here
            setExistingToken(token)
        }
    }, [])

    return [existingToken, tokenLocalCheck]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant put async/await on a useEffect method. even if you wrap a function around useEffect, it will not use the async/await.

check this out though!

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326